# how to set wallpaper fixed and scrollable same like OGQ Backgrounds HD App do's in android

Tags: android, wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I wants to  set wallpaper fixed and scrollable.
This is link to the OGQ Backgrounds HD App.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ogqcorp.bgh

That app screen shots attached here, The same way i wants to do any how.
please suggest any library or reflection class code, hacking or any other code.[image: Scrollable Standard Wallpaper]

[image: Fixed Fit to screen Wallpaper]

[image: Fixed Fit Center Wallpaper]

Answer (score 0):

Have you fixed the problem yet? If not, try using the `WallpaperManager` class.

- Simply call method `setWallpaperOffsetSteps`, this method would enable you to edit the offset of the wallpaper based on your existing windows tabs in your android phone.

example(this should be put under your `onCreate()` in your activity class)

```
//For fixed wallpaper
      int x,y;
        x = 0; //this is the offset X axis delta from one windows tab to another
        y = 0; // same for Y axis
        WallpaperManager wmng = (WallpaperManager) this.getSystemService(this.WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
        wmng.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(x,y);

//For scrollable
        x = 1; 
        y = 1; 
        wmng.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(x,y);
```

and remember to put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />` in your android Manifest

reference:*https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager#setWallpaperOffsetSteps(float,%20float)*

Comment: It is not work, at least on some devices.